# LOAD DATA INFILE on remote machine

Tags: mysql, linux, unix

How would I do the following command, with a local file, on a remote database (different machine) ?

```
$MYSQL_PATH/mysql -u root -h remote.net files -e "
    LOAD DATA INFILE '$1'
    INTO TABLE $TABLE_NAME
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
      (size, @d2, @d3, @d4, @d5, path)
```

The problem seems to be that the INFILE at `/tmp/infile.txt` is not being recognized remotely. What would be the correct way to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` loads a file on machine the MySQL server is running on.

Use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` to load a file located on your client machine.

Answer (score 10):

Don't forget to include `--local-infile=1` when doing this:

```
$MYSQL_PATH/mysql -u root -h remote.net files --local-infile=1 -e "
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE...
```